# Is there a 'native' cross platform calendar GUI view example available for Titanium?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, calendar, cross-platform, titanium

As usual, the Q&A section of Appcelerator's developer website isn't being very helpful with this question (unless I'm going blind). It seems that this question is largely asked but never answered.

Is there an example of a calendar view (the GUI - e.g. day, week and month view) that can be deployed to both iOS **AND** Android? Integration into the built-in calendar (or events) isn't a must (it's not required now but may be in the future).

I've seen [stelford](https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar) and [smontgomerie's](https://github.com/smontgomerie/Appcelerator-Calendar-Module) modules for iOS and [pec1985's](https://github.com/pec1985/Calendar-View-for-Appcelerator-v2) web view one, however, I'm after one that would result with native (cancels out pec1985's one) GUI objects so that disability assistive technologies are enabled for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no.

the implementations of the calendar UI on the two platforms is so drastically different and complex that the probability of finding one implementation to meet all of your requirements is highly unlikely.

You are not going blind, your requirements are just very specific.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought my requirements are very specific... I'm just after some example code where someone has successfully deployed a calendar view (using multiple views or whatever) on both Android/uiOS. Thank you for your answer, however (I recognise you and your status within the Titanium community).

Comment: Aaron is indeed correct. I could not find any examples anywhere. I was able to do up a quick calendar proof of concept using views that displayed in both iOS and Android in about 2-3 hours. I'll be using this as the basis for my calendar in my app.

Comment: Could you share a bit about your approach? Did you roll your own calendar completely from scratch? Or did you use an off-the-shelf component for iOS and something else for Android?

Comment: @DanPorts I wrote it completely myself from scratch.

Basically, I created a grid of views with some simple calculations about how many cols/rows there should be and then painted the views with labels.  It took a while to get right, but works pretty nicely on both Android and iOS.

Comment: OK, that's what I was guessing. Thanks. If you ever decided to sell that or release it as open source I'm guessing you would see a good deal of interest in it, judging by various questions I've seen on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

I Google a lot for showing Month View / Calendar View in my Titanium application but unable to find it out which work on IPhone and Android (Almost all the screens) Both.

After that I tried to implement it by my own and got the good implementation.

To achieve this, Create project which support Android & IPhone.
Open app.js and replace the following code with the existing code and after that Press Command + Shift + F to format the code.

[image: Image here]

```
// Taking Screen Width
var screenWidth = 322;
var needToChangeSize = false;

var screenWidthActual = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android') {
if (screenWidthActual >= 641) {
screenWidth = screenWidthActual;
needToChangeSize = true;
}
}

// Main Window of the Month View.
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor : '#FF000000',
navBarHidden : true
});

// Button at the buttom side
var backButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
bottom : '20dp',
height : '40dp',
width : '200dp'
});

// Previous Button - Tool Bar
var prevMonth = Ti.UI.createButton({
left : '15dp',
width : 'auto',
height : 'auto',
title : '<'
});

// Next Button - Tool Bar
var nextMonth = Ti.UI.createButton({
right : '15dp',
width : 'auto',
height : 'auto',
title : '>'
});

// Month Title - Tool Bar
var monthTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
width : '200dp',
height : '24dp',
textAlign : 'center',
color : '#3a4756',
font : {
fontSize : 20,
fontWeight : 'bold'
}
});

// Tool Bar
var toolBar = Ti.UI.createView({
top : '0dp',
width : '322dp',
height : '50dp',
backgroundColor : '#FFFFD800',
layout : 'vertical'
});

// Tool Bar - View which contain Title Prev. & Next Button
var toolBarTitle = Ti.UI.createView({
top : '3dp',
width : '322dp',
height : '24dp'
});

toolBarTitle.add(prevMonth);
toolBarTitle.add(monthTitle);
toolBarTitle.add(nextMonth);

// Tool Bar - Day's
var toolBarDays = Ti.UI.createView({
top : '2dp',
width : '322dp',
height : '22dp',
layout : 'horizontal',
left : '-1dp'
});

toolBarDays.sunday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Sun',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.monday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Mon',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.tuesday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Tue',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.wednesday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Wed',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.thursday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Thu',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.friday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Fri',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.saturday = Ti.UI.createLabel({
left : '0dp',
height : '20dp',
text : 'Sat',
width : '46dp',
textAlign : 'center',
font : {
fontSize : 12,
fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : '#3a4756'
});

toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.sunday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.monday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.tuesday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.wednesday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.thursday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.friday);
toolBarDays.add(toolBarDays.saturday);

// Adding Tool Bar Title View & Tool Bar Days View
toolBar.add(toolBarTitle);
toolBar.add(toolBarDays);

// Function which create day view template
dayView = function(e) {
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
current : e.current,
width : '46dp',
height : '44dp',
backgroundColor : '#FFDCDCDF',
text : e.day,
textAlign : 'center',
color : e.color,
font : {
fontSize : 20,
fontWeight : 'bold'
}
});
return label;
};

monthName = function(e) {
switch(e) {
case 0:
e = 'January';
break;
case 1:
e = 'February';
break;
case 2:
e = 'March';
break;
case 3:
e = 'April';
break;
case 4:
e = 'May';
break;
case 5:
e = 'June';
break;
case 6:
e = 'July';
break;
case 7:
e = 'August';
break;
case 8:
e = 'September';
break;
case 9:
e = 'October';
break;
case 10:
e = 'November';
break;
case 11:
e = 'December';
break;
};
return e;
};

// Calendar Main Function
var calView = function(a, b, c) {
var nameOfMonth = monthName(b);

//create main calendar view
var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
layout : 'horizontal',
width : '322dp',
height : 'auto',
top : '50dp'
});

//set the time
var daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(a, b, 32).getDate();
var dayOfMonth = new Date(a, b, c).getDate();
var dayOfWeek = new Date(a, b, 1).getDay();
var daysInLastMonth = 32 - new Date(a, b - 1, 32).getDate();
var daysInNextMonth = (new Date(a, b, daysInMonth).getDay()) - 6;

//set initial day number
var dayNumber = daysInLastMonth - dayOfWeek + 1;

//get last month's days
for ( i = 0; i < dayOfWeek; i++) {
mainView.add(new dayView({
day : dayNumber,
color : '#8e959f',
current : 'no',
dayOfMonth : ''
}));
dayNumber++;
};

// reset day number for current month
dayNumber = 1;

//get this month's days
for ( i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++) {
var newDay = new dayView({
day : dayNumber,
color : '#3a4756',
current : 'yes',
dayOfMonth : dayOfMonth
});
mainView.add(newDay);
if (newDay.text == dayOfMonth) {
newDay.color = 'white';
// newDay.backgroundImage='../libraries/calendar/pngs/monthdaytiletoday_selected.png';
newDay.backgroundColor = '#FFFFF000';
var oldDay = newDay;
}
dayNumber++;
};
dayNumber = 1;

//get remaining month's days
for ( i = 0; i > daysInNextMonth; i--) {
mainView.add(new dayView({
day : dayNumber,
color : '#8e959f',
current : 'no',
dayOfMonth : ''
}));
dayNumber++;
};

// this is the new "clicker" function, although it doesn't have a name anymore, it just is.
mainView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if (e.source.current == 'yes') {

// reset last day selected
if (oldDay.text == dayOfMonth) {
oldDay.color = 'white';
// oldDay.backgroundImage='../libraries/calendar/pngs/monthdaytiletoday.png';
oldDay.backgroundColor = '#FFFFF000';
} else {
oldDay.color = '#3a4756';
// oldDay.backgroundImage='../libraries/calendar/pngs/monthdaytile-Decoded.png';
oldDay.backgroundColor = '#FFDCDCDF'
}
oldDay.backgroundPaddingLeft = '0dp';
oldDay.backgroundPaddingBottom = '0dp';

// set window title with day selected, for testing purposes only
backButton.title = nameOfMonth + ' ' + e.source.text + ', ' + a;

// set characteristic of the day selected
if (e.source.text == dayOfMonth) {
// e.source.backgroundImage='../libraries/calendar/pngs/monthdaytiletoday_selected.png';
e.source.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00FF';
} else {
// e.source.backgroundImage='../libraries/calendar/pngs/monthdaytile_selected.png';
e.source.backgroundColor = '#FFFF0000';
}
e.source.backgroundPaddingLeft = '1dp';
e.source.backgroundPaddingBottom = '1dp';
e.source.color = 'white';
//this day becomes old :(
oldDay = e.source;
}
});

return mainView;
};

// what's today's date?
var setDate = new Date();
a = setDate.getFullYear();
b = setDate.getMonth();
c = setDate.getDate();

// add the three calendar views to the window for changing calendars with animation later

var prevCalendarView = null;
if (b == 0) {
prevCalendarView = calView(a - 1, 11, c);
} else {
prevCalendarView = calView(a, b - 1, c);
}
prevCalendarView.left = (screenWidth * -1) + 'dp';

var nextCalendarView = null;
if (b == 0) {
nextCalendarView = calView(a + 1, 0, c);
} else {
nextCalendarView = calView(a, b + 1, c);
}
nextCalendarView.left = screenWidth + 'dp';

var thisCalendarView = calView(a, b, c);
if (needToChangeSize == false) {
thisCalendarView.left = '-1dp';
}

monthTitle.text = monthName(b) + ' ' + a;

backButton.title = monthName(b) + ' ' + c + ', ' + a;

// add everything to the window
win.add(toolBar);
win.add(thisCalendarView);
win.add(nextCalendarView);
win.add(prevCalendarView);
win.add(backButton);

// yeah, open the window, why not?
win.open({
modal : true
});

var slideNext = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
// left : '-322',
duration : 500
});

slideNext.left = (screenWidth * -1);

var slideReset = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
// left : '-1',
duration : 500
});

if (needToChangeSize == false) {
slideReset.left = '-1';
} else {
slideReset.left = ((screenWidth - 644) / 2);
}

var slidePrev = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
// left : '322',
duration : 500
});

slidePrev.left = screenWidth;

// Next Month Click Event
nextMonth.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (b == 11) {
b = 0;
a++;
} else {
b++;
}

thisCalendarView.animate(slideNext);
nextCalendarView.animate(slideReset);

setTimeout(function() {
thisCalendarView.left = (screenWidth * -1) + 'dp';
if (needToChangeSize == false) {
nextCalendarView.left = '-1dp';
} else {
nextCalendarView.left = ((screenWidth - 644) / 2);
}
prevCalendarView = thisCalendarView;
thisCalendarView = nextCalendarView;
if (b == 11) {
nextCalendarView = calView(a + 1, 0, c);
} else {
nextCalendarView = calView(a, b + 1, c);
}
monthTitle.text = monthName(b) + ' ' + a;
nextCalendarView.left = screenWidth + 'dp';
win.add(nextCalendarView);
}, 500);
});

// Previous Month Click Event
prevMonth.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (b == 0) {
b = 11;
a--;
} else {
b--;
}
thisCalendarView.animate(slidePrev);
prevCalendarView.animate(slideReset);
setTimeout(function() {
thisCalendarView.left = screenWidth + 'dp';
if (needToChangeSize == false) {
prevCalendarView.left = '-1dp';
} else {
prevCalendarView.left = ((screenWidth - 644) / 2);
}
nextCalendarView = thisCalendarView;
thisCalendarView = prevCalendarView;
if (b == 0) {
prevCalendarView = calView(a - 1, 11, c);
} else {
prevCalendarView = calView(a, b - 1, c);
}
monthTitle.text = monthName(b) + ' ' + a;
prevCalendarView.left = (screenWidth * -1) + 'dp';
win.add(prevCalendarView);
}, 500);
});
```

Tested Environment
Titanium Studio - 2.1.2.201208301612
Titanium SDK - 2.1.0.GA
Android - 2.2 Emulator
iOS Version - 5.0

Reference - http://titaniumexplorers.blogspot.in/2012/09/titanium-calendar-month-view.html

Comment: @AvtarSingh backButton.title = a+'-'+selelectedmonthidentifier + '-' + e.source.text;
here i need to select any date means go to next window ? how can i do ?